# sshd regular exit code 255

Tags: network, wifi, ssh

I'm a novice at network things. I enabled remote-login on my home mac (OS 10.12.5) so I could git between home and office. To make it work, I had to tell the wifi to fix my Mac's IP and to redirect Port 22 to it. Works fine. My log file, however, has thousands of messages (one every few seconds) of the form:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd._hex_[_int_]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
```

Nothing in the log explicitly mentions a refused authentication, and I don't seem to have an `auth.log` or `secure.log` file (other posts suggested to look in there).

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885748/ssh-script-returns-255-error)

Comment: Do you have Little Snitch or a similar firewall program installed?

Comment: @user2707001 : I have the OSX firewall on, but nothing else. I didn't post this because I assumed the Mac built-ins should play well together. Will edit question if you think it might be relevant.

Comment: @Paradoxis: Thanks for the link. It's a bit above my level, but I'm not (purposely) running anything on the home Mac that invokes ssh commands. Home mac is the Git 'origin' and 'remote' is office. Will Git automatically try to contact remotes? Also: remote currently shut down, and likewise has (to my knowledge) no scripts trying to contact origin.

Comment: Could you check from office Mac: `ssh home_mac pwd` and if it gives an error, add this information to your OQ?

Comment: @danielAzuelos Can't get to office at present, but I successfully logged in using a mac terminal connected to a different network (i.e., had to go through my wifi router to get to my computer). No error messages.

Comment: @danielAzuelos : I see you changed the title, so does that mean I can be confident that these errors are _not_ part of an automated probing sort of thing? I had of course read [this guys posted logs](http://www.benjaminfleischer.com/2015/02/16/brute-force-ssh-attack/), which have many messages that my logs do _not_ have, but of course I'm not qualified to rule out an attack. Is there telltale sign of such activity?

Comment: Within your OQ there is no evidence that there might be any attack against your `sshd`. Your problem should be analysed first. I changed your title to avoid bad or unrelated answers.

Comment: Please, since you have many computers, avoid the term "my computer" which leads to a total confusion. I further suggest you to give them names like for ex. `alex`, `beatrix`…

Comment: @danielAzuelos Good point, thanks. I'll use git terminology. `origin` (home) gets to internet via `wifiRouter`. `remote` (office) has fixed IP. I successfully got through to `origin` from unrelated computer `zulu` which was connected to distant internet (not related to `origin` or `remote` network). `remote` is shutdown. `origin` should not be initiating connections. Errors appear on `origin`. I was considering editing sshd_config on `origin` to increase logging to DEBUG. Man page says this "violates users privacy," but that just means I will be logging my own data on `origin`, no?

Comment: Right! You can already *violate your own privacy* with the `-v` option of `ssh`.

Comment: I advise you not to edit `sshd_config` for 2 reasons: I suspect the problem isn't there, this conf. file is very powerful and very easily broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the log entry performed when `sshd` denies a connection. You're probably seeing unauthorised users trying to brute force their way in by trying common usernames and passwords. There used to also be a log entry directly from `sshd` itself telling you the IP address and username attempted, but Apple has decided to labotomize standard UNIX logging from `sshd`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ForceCommand` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to override certain ssh commands, then check if that works properly with all users that might log in over ssh.

In my case, the script that was called with `ForceCommand` tried to write to a file that not every ssh user was allowed to write to. As a consequence, the command failed with "Permission denied" which caused the script to return a non-zero return-code, and because of this, ssh logged `Service exited with abnormal code: 255`.